Godaddy subdomain to Google Cloud CDN
Is it possible to have a subdomain in Godaddy forwarding access to Google Cloud CDN?
I see that to have control over Godaddy domain's in GCP I would have to create a zone in Cloud DNS and have the nameservers configured in Godaddy, but what if I only want to have control over the subdomain, or having that subdomain pointing to Cloud CDN by any other approach, do I still have to create a zone for that?

No, you would only create a zone if you want to delegate ownership of that namespace to some other name server(s). If you just want a subdomain to resolve to an IP address that Google owns, simply create an address (A) or alias (CNAME) record. However, if the Google endpoint expects TLS, you will run into problems since its certificate wouldn't cover it, so what you really want is a reverse proxy.

I agree with @Rafael that you need to set up A and CNAME records for this. You are also required to create a GCP load balancer for your use case.

@Ponsy I created a load balancer for that CDN, what I'm not sure is about the CDN domain, in GCP we have to point to a certificate for the load balancer and we also have to specify a domain for the CDN, both must be the same value I believe, that domain is a subdomain in Godaddy, specified by an A record, how does Google now that subdomain is mine?

Cloud CDN uses global anycasted IP addresses so you just need to have an A or AAAA record in your zone file at GoDaddy depending if you want IPv4/IPv6 support. No need for a reverse proxy- use a reserved IP address for HTTP and HTTPS. Decorate the frontend service with the same IP for HTTP and HTTPS frontends. For the HTTPS cert, you can use a Google Cloud cert where Google Trust Services will validate the domain by validating your hostname when you point the anycasted A/AAAA record to the anycasted IP- that serves as proof that you own the domain. This takes about 20 minutes to deploy.

Cloud CDN actually doesn't know you own that subdomain. What matters is that you need to update your A or AAAA records on your GoDaddy to point it to the GCP load balancer’s IP address, and mapping the correct domain on GCP.

@Dave is probably right. Deploying a reverse proxy would be a sub-optimal, last-resort solution. Since this is a common use case, they likely offer first-class support. Check the docs on custom domains. The point is that you have to consider TLS as well.
